# CH3MNAS Fun Plug and NZBget. Cannot launch NzbGet 0.7, word unexpected

Tags: command-line, shell, ssh

I have un-tarred the nzbget0.70 debug version and have put it in the `/ffp/bin` dir. and I have a config file in the `/ffp/etc/` dir

but when I try to run it, I get the following:

```
root@NAS:/mnt/HD_a2/ffp/bin# nzbget
-sh: nzbget: not found
root@NAS:/mnt/HD_a2/ffp/bin# sh nzbget
nzbget: line 1: syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I used this how-to: http://www.aroundmyroom.com/2009/01/27/the-how-to-that-replaces-all/

I used this tar: **nzbget-0.7.0-bin-dns323-arm-debug.tar.gz**
from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nzbget/files/

what did I do wrong?

ps. I logged in as root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nzbget` is a binary file; you can't use `sh` to process it, you would do that if `nzbget` were a shell script. Running just `nzbget` didn't work because by default the current directory is not on the PATH, so you need to do something like:

```
$ ./nzbget
```

Or:

```
$ /mnt/HD_a2/ffp/bin/nzbget
```

Comment: You are right. I had to use a special build for the ch3Mnas and then run it like this: ./nzbget -D -c /ffp/etc/nzbget.conf